# Regex: matching nested parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following string:

```
(first group) (second group) (third group)hello example (words(more words) here) something
```

The desired matches would be:

```
(first group)
(second group)
(third group)
(words(more words) here)
```

I've tried to build a regex as follows:

```
/\(.*?\)/g
```

But it matches the following:

```
(first group)
(second group)
(third group)
(words(more words)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since this needs to be done in JavaScript, we have two options:

a) specify a pattern with a fixed nesting depth (this seems to be case here):

```
\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\)
```

```js
const regex = /\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\)/g;
const str = `(first group) (econd group) (third group)hello example (words(more words) here) something`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Or use XRegexp (or a similar library) that implements recursive matching:

```js
const str = `(first group) (econd group) (third group)hello example (words(more words) here) something`;
console.log(XRegExp.matchRecursive(str, '\\(', '\\)', 'g'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/xregexp@4.3.0/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try out the below regular expression which uses recursion

```
\(([^()]|(?R))*\)
```

Comment: Invalid regular expression: Invalid group.

Comment: The escape sequence backslash was not getting posted for some reason. Please add like \\(([^()]|(?R))*\\).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work in your case. `\((?:[^()]|\([^()]+\))+\)`.

Side note: Not too proud of how I did this.